# Moving a drop down navigation

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, dropdown

I have some difficulties trying to center my dropdown navigation.

Below I posted an image of the current design and some CSS.

As you can see, the dropdown doesn't fit on the page.

[image]

```
.structure-mainnavigation ul li ul {
width:500px;
}
.structure-mainnavigation ul li ul li {
width:25%;
float:left;
text-align: center;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So the main menu or the submenu is not centered? Cause to me it looks like the main menu is not centered:)

Comment: It's great that you added some CSS, but it would be more helpful if you had some HTML and probably a little more CSS to go with it. This is minimal, but not complete or verifiable (see [mcve]). In its current state, it will be very hard for people to give meaningful answers.

Comment: @lumio the main is centred perfectly, its just the way the picture was cropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around for hours and hours i solved my own problem by adding the following code:

```
li:hover ul { left:auto; right:0; }
```

Comment: Did you set `left` before somewhere else? Try using the direct selector like `li:hover > ul` so only uls in one level are selected and not all the way down the tree

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

position: absolute;
margin:0 auto;

when you say centering you mean to put drop down on center of the page or center of menu item?

Comment: I mean centered below the category, so it would be central to "Gift By Type"